# C# stuck between having getter and setter and default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have in my class:

```
public class submitRequest
{
    public int students { get; set; } = 0;
```

When I send **from frontend to backend** a non-number (e.g. null, or empty string), it does not use default value and I get:

```
"The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.students"
```

But when I only have

```
 public int students { get; } = 0;
```

it works fine. But then I have problems that correct values (1, 2, ...) sent from frontend are ignored, and the value of students is always 0.

Comment: Could you add a minimal example of the JSON and the code needed to reproduce the problem to the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newtonsoft how to deserialize null to default value again after switching to .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71588334/newtonsoft-how-to-deserialize-null-to-default-value-again-after-switching-to-ne)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the default value is not used when you send a non-number value from the frontend is because the deserialization process fails and an exception is thrown.

To handle this situation, you can make the `students` property nullable by changing its type to `int?`:

```
public class SubmitRequest
{
    public int? Students { get; set; }
}
```

By making the property nullable, the deserialization process will succeed even if the JSON value is null or not a valid integer.

If the JSON value is null, the property will be set to null. If the JSON value is not a valid integer, the property will be set to null as well.

Comment: This hit me a few years ago, too. Deserialization does not use default property values! The other option is to specify the default value in your JSON instead of in the api.